# ceiling mount shower curtain rod

Tags: bathroom, shower

I am currently (slowly) re-modeling a small bathroom (about 32 sq/ft) and I have small problem with the shower curtain rod.  The space is small, and one of the walls that the shower curtain rod would mount to has a piece of window trim.  Currently there is an adjustable rod that is fit between the two walls, and it works, but its ugly.

I am looking for possible suggestions for a shower curtain rod installation, perhaps hanging from the wall above where the rod is currently installed.  See the pictures below for a better idea of what I'm talking about.

[image: Left side]

[image: Right side]

Also, I was looking at [Ceiling Shower Rod](http://www.ceilingshowerrod.com/new/) which looks decent.  I'm not sure if this is the best solution though.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to use a pressure mounted curtain rod *inside* of the shower stall?  The lower picture (the right side of the shower stall?) looks like the start of the shower stall wall is flat but the top picture (left side of shower stall?) looks slightly curved.  But still I wonder if you move the shower curtain rod below where it curves on the left, then is it flat enough on both sides for the pressure from the curtain rod to hold it in place?

Answer (score 1):

They make aluminium rail systems that can be mounted to the ceiling, this might be a good option for you.  I did a quick search and found this one, which looks fairly nice [RECMAR 4372 Deluxe Shower Curtain Kit](http://www.sailrite.com/RECMAR-4372-Deluxe-Shower-Curtain-Kit-72-Long).

[image: RECMAR 4372 Deluxe Shower Curtain Kit]

I have a similar setup in my bathroom (not this make/model) but it does not have the rollers, it's just a channel that the hangers slide in. The rollers seem like a nice feature, as mine can easily bind up causing me to rip the curtain as I try to close it.

Answer (score 1):

[ikea ceiling mount curtain rail](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00079362)

This is what I ended up using in my bathroom. Nice, cheap, and has the ability to go around corners.

Comment: have you noticed any problems with binding?  I have one similar to that, and the hooks bind up all the time (and I end up ripping the curtain when I try to close it).

Comment: Yes, especially when I move the curtain around corners. You have to pull towards the top of the curtain. Since mine is going around a jacuzzi tub, this was the most effective and cheapest solution that I could find.